# Probability under Uncertainity

Tags: probability

Consider $B$, $W \in E(\Omega)$ be two events in an event space $E(\Omega)$ where the occurrence of event $W$ uncertain. Let this uncertainty of $W$ be denoted as $\overline{W}$.

Possible outcomes of both the events are: $B = \{1\}$ and $W = \{0, 1\}$

What could be the probability of event $B$ occurring given that event $W$ is uncertain?.

In short, $P(B = 1|\overline{W})$ = ?

Comment: What a strange question. Since the uncertainty of $W$ doesn’t seem to be an event, as far as I can infer, the expression $P(B=1| \bar{W})$ is meaningless. Basic conditional probability conditions on *events*.

Comment: @LoveTooNap29 You are right! I am scratching my head around this for many hours!

Comment: Is your description identical to the original text? If not could you paste here the original version. (As otheres noted above, your version is confusing -- sorry to say that.)

Comment: @zoli Description I posted above is identical to the original text! I am also confused with that!